# Map box access token issue using jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mapbox

I am using Map box with jetpack composable. I have did all the configuration according to the [mapBox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/). But still it is giving me error like

```
com.mapbox.maps.MapboxConfigurationException: Using MapView, MapSurface, Snapshotter 
or other Map components requires providing a valid access token when inflating or 
creating the map.
                                                                                                
Provide the token by either:
  1. Creating a mapbox_access_token string resource.
  2. Or programmatically calling `MapboxOptions.accessToken = <your_access_token>`.
The access token parameter is required when using a Mapbox service.
```

Following is the `composable` code.

```
      MapboxMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        mapInitOptionsFactory = { context ->
            MapInitOptions(
                context = context,
                styleUri = Style.SATELLITE_STREETS,
            )
        },
        mapViewportState = MapViewportState().apply {
            setCameraOptions {
                zoom(2.0)
                center(Point.fromLngLat(-98.0, 39.5))
                pitch(0.0)
                bearing(0.0)
            }
        },
    ) // : MapboxMap
```

Following is the `settings.grade.kts` file.

```
   pluginManagement {
                    repositories {
                        google()
                        mavenCentral()
                        gradlePluginPortal()
                    }
                }
                
                dependencyResolutionManagement {
                    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
                    repositories {
                        google()
                        mavenCentral()
                        maven {
                            url = uri("https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven")
                            // Do not change the username below. It should always be "mapbox" (not your username).
                            credentials.username = "mapbox"
                            // Use the secret token stored in gradle.properties as the password
                            credentials.password = providers.gradleProperty("MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN").get()
                            authentication.create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                rootProject.name = "HikingBuddy"
                include(":app")
                include(":country_code_compilation")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have the Downloads token, but there is no Default public token in your code example. Maybe you miss that one by any chance? https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install#configure-credentials

Comment: Yep that was the issue. Accepted your answer.